# Python - delete part of link in array

Tags: python, string, replace, hyperlink

I have a list of links in an array, such as

```
results = [link1/1254245,
           'q%(random part)cache:link2/1254245& (random part) Dclnk',
           'link3/1254245]
```

whereas `link = http://www.whatever.com`.

I want to replace the term `q%3(random part)cache` and `&(random part)Dclnk` with nothing so that the "clean" `link2` is "cut" out and left over among the other "clean" links. The random part changes always in content and length. The `q%3 :` and `& Dclnk` stay the same.

How do I do that? I could not find a straight answer to that so far.

Comment: So guys, coming back to this because it is still not working for my scrape here is my extracted string which has the url I want in it: ´qxkYULVJKkNI1_PptQ"><b>dfmklsdmfstr:htt://www.compandlink.uk/3771840a\xc3\x9fe</b> 10 GmbH ', 'q%3Dcache:LkZ7W1AQujoJ:comp24.info/compinformationen/DE/…; _______so I want everythinf from the http until the end of the digit sequence 3771840. How can I do this?  the length from http://...3771840 stays the same if this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this through `re.sub` and list comprehension.

```
>>> l = ['link1/1254245', 'q%(random part)cache:link2/1254245& (random part) Dclnk', 'link3/1254245']
>>> [re.sub(r'q%[^(]*\([^()]*\)cache:|&\s*\([^()]*\)\s*Dclnk', r'', i) for i in l]
['link1/1254245', 'link2/1254245', 'link3/1254245']
```

`[^()]*` matches any character but not of `(` or `)` zero or more times. Specify an `|` alteration operator to use multiple patterns.

Comment: because i didn't find `3` in your input, i used `q%[^(]*` instead of `q%3`

Comment: Thank you very much Avanish. Exactly what I needed; See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm for further syntax; and impot re first

Comment: Glad it worked out.. If you use regex on your code, you must need to import re module.

Comment: q%3Dcache:LkZ7W1AQujoJ:http://www.unternehmenhszd.info/Firmeninfsacheonen/DE/3771840%252Bbeisstrasse%2Bsite:unternehmenhszd.info%26hl%3Dde%26%26ct%3Dclnk   I ran the code over this example and, unfortunately, it does not cut out the clean link (http://...until...DE/3771840). Can s.o. please help

Comment: replace `[^(]*\([^()]*\)` in the above regex with `.*?`

Comment: Tank you very much. Unfortunately, still not working. However, I found another way I don't know the syntax for: if the length of the string element in the array is >= 60 the string should be cut out from character position 14 to 40. The rest of the string, i.e. 1-13 and 41-60 should be deleted. Maybe s.o. can advice here

Comment: Here is how to solve my question problem .2 
`link = 'pVZJhXXgHUsJ:http://www.whatever.info/whatever/UK/3887988%252Bm%2B'

sub_link = link[13:57]
print sub_link`

Comment: add the above comment to your question.